# PHP application cannot connect to Oracle Cloud Database

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I am researching the Oracle Cloud Database.
I created an Oracle Database and one table named `Employee`.

I wrote a PHP script to connect to this database, however it can't connect.

```
$conn = oci_connect('SYS', '1234567', 'localhost:1521/PDB1.590848312.oraclecloud.internal');
```

It throws this error:

```
[code] => 12154  
[message] => ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified  
[offset] => 0  
[sqltext] =>
```

Comment: Did you open an SSH tunnel to the database server before trying to connect through localhost?

Comment: On the other hand, assuming you're using localhost in the question just so you don't give out the actual ip.

Did you open port 1521 on the Cloud database?  It is closed by default.